# gridview that is updated frequently

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a `ASP.NET` `gridview` that shows some entries from the database. The entries need to be updated very frequently (if a modification occurs on the database, it should be reflected in the asp.net website within at most 3seconds).

The solution I am thinking about is to put the `gridview` inside an update panel and refresh the page every 3 seconds. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

By using Timer in the update panel u can perform that update operation.For example ..

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="10000">
            </asp:Timer>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="UpdatePanel1 not refreshed yet."></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="UpdatePanel2 not refreshed yet."></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </form>
```

instead of label control u can use gridview.

Comment: do you consider this being efficient?