# Sending new database records to the website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

We have several terminals throughout the plant that employees will be using to submit part requests through our supply/warehouse department.

This Supply Warehouse will have a terminal displaying an "orders" website, showing a list of part numbers and the employees who are waiting for them.

Everything works now, but I only know how to get the data to refresh by coding in a `<META REFRESH>` tag, which doesn't really work well and causes a lot of other information on the form to get lost in the process.

How would I go about telling the webpage to "listen" for changes or simply update the GridView once a minute or so?

I've seen websites do it. This site pops up a note as soon as someone responds, finance sites pop up the latest stock quotes every few seconds, etc. I don't know what the technology is called or how I would use it.

Do I write some code in the codebehind?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // ???
}
```

Here is the basics of what I have.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="productionDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPWEB_PRODUCTION %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [RequestID], [Employee], [DateStamp], [Line], [PartNo], [Workorder], [Qty], [MTF], [Status] FROM [vwRequestsEx] WHERE ([Status] = @Status)"><SelectParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSelector" Name="Status" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="1" DataSourceID="productionDataSource2" EmptyDataText="No Records to Display" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewRow_Selected" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" RowHeaderColumn="RequestID" Width="95%">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestID" HeaderText="RequestID" SortExpression="RequestID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee" HeaderText="Employee" SortExpression="Employee" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateStamp" HeaderText="DateStamp" SortExpression="DateStamp" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Line" HeaderText="Line" SortExpression="Line" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PartNo" HeaderText="PartNo" SortExpression="PartNo" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Workorder" HeaderText="Workorder" SortExpression="Workorder" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="Qty" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="MTF" HeaderText="MTF" SortExpression="MTF" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I'm getting a lot of downvotes lately. Downvoters: That's OK, but kindly let me know why so I'll understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy solution using UpdatePanels and a Timer in the answer to this question: [gridview that is updated frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533288/gridview-that-is-updated-frequently)

Comment: Looks promising. I see a reference to some `ScriptManager1` and the Timer's `Tick` event, but no code behind. Do you know if the `ScriptManager1` needs something to make this work?

Comment: Actually I think you'd just need a Timer1_Tick event in the code-behind that probably just calls GridView1.DataBind(); and ScriptManager just needs to be present on the page. There are other ways to do this type of thing using jQuery or if you were on MVC, but this is the easier to wrap around what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using [SignalR](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid/ProductShowCase/SignalR) to achieve this.

Comment: That certainly looks neat. Wished I understood it. :(

Comment: I did. When it starts with `@`, does that mean MVC code (like jQuery using `$` in code).

Comment: It looks like a plugin using MVC/Razor and jQuery